# Accessing the out parameter of a Function when it is invoked through a Func

Tags: c#, lambda, func, out-parameters

Apologies I haven't done very well with the title of the question, hopefully it will be apparenent with some code

I've created a class that stores poker hand information as follows

```
public class BestHandSummary<T>
{
    public Func<T, bool> Test { get; set; }
    public Ranking Rank { get; set; } //Enum: Nothing, TwoPair, Straight, Flush, Poker :in ascending order
    public int BestCard { get; set; }
    public BestHand(Ranking r)
    {
        Rank = r;
    }
    ..//default ctor
}
```

I initialised the rules collection in order of most valuable hand so that when I take the First() of the matched rules the most powerful hand will be chosen as best hand.

```
rules = new List<BestHandSummary<PokerHand>>()
{
    new BestHandSummary<PokerHand> { Test = h => h.HandContainsFourOfAKind(out bestCard), 
                              Rank = Ranking.FourOfAKind,
                              BestCard = bestCard },
    new BestHandSummary<PokerHand> { Test = h => h.HandContainsFlush(), 
                              Rank = Ranking.Flush },
    new BestHandSummary<PokerHand> { Test = h => h.HandContainsStraight(out bestCard), 
                              Rank = Ranking.Straight,
                              BestCard = bestCard },
    new BestHandSummary<PokerHand> { Test = h => h.HandContainsTwoPair(out bestCard), 
                                      Rank = Ranking.Straight,
                                      BestCard = bestCard },

};
private BestHandSummary<PokerHand> GetAPlayersBestHand(PokerHand hand)
{
   bool hasAny = rules.Any(r => r.Test(hand));
   if (hasAny)
   {
       return rules.Where(r => r.Test(hand) == true).First();
   }
   return new BestHandSummary<PokerHand>(Ranking.Nothing);
}
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how can I tunnel the out param bestCard into the BestCard property of the BestHandSummary class? The code above doesn't work, BestCard = bestCard doestn't get assigned, which I can understand why, but I'm wondering if there is any small change I can make to fix it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int bestCard;

new BestHand<PokerHand> { Test = h => h.HandContainsFourOfAKind(out bestCard), 
                              Rank = Ranking.FourOfAKind,
                              BestCard = bestCard },
```

This code won't work, because `HandContainsFourOfAKind` was never called, and so nothing was assigned to `bestCard`.

> I'm only interested in bestCard when the rule matched. It is used for when there is a draw between two players. E.G. H= 22KJJ -> best card is Jack, not king

So, you want `BestCard` to be assigned only when `Test` is invoked? This will do.

```
var hand = new BestHand<PokerHand> {Rank = Ranking.FourOfAKind};
hand.Test = h => 
     {
        int bestCard; //var local to the lambda's scope
        bool contains = h.HandContainsFourOfAKind(out bestCard);
        hand.BestCard = bestCard;
        return contains;
     };
```

Comment: I'm only interested in bestCard when the rule matched. It is used for when there is a draw between two players. E.G. Player 1= 22KJJ -> best card is Jack, not king , Player 2 = 33AQQ -> bestCard Q. Since both have 2 pair I can use p2 bestcard of Q to determine winner

Answer (score 0):

I've written an equalizer myself a few years ago. I don't have a direct answer to your question, but one thing comes to my mind:

In your example, if you just look at the best card involved building the rank like the Jack in the two-pair hand, you won't figure out the best hand, if both have the same two-pair with different kicker. You might have to use a third method on that.
Maybe you are better of to do this in one piece. I solved this with an if-monster, which returned an exact long-value, indicating every card in it's value for that hand.

Comment: Valid point but I'm actually sticking to a brief, its a simple simulator which doesn't implement all the rules correctly. For instance i.e p1:44778 p2: 4477Q is a draw but p1:44778 p2:44QQ2 P2 Wins